# JavaScript library which lets you combine seemingly unrelated charts

Tags: library, javascript, charts

Let me keep it quick and simple before giving anymore context.

Can someone recommend me a JavaScript library which:

- Lets you combine seemingly unrelated charts. E.g. Gantt chart and line chart

  => both charts have different series but should be overlayed on top of each other
- Free or lifetime license

What have I looked at?

[Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart)
=> free, can combine charts but only a certain type of charts (not including the Gantt chart)

[amChart](https://www.amcharts.com/) => free (to some extent) but not able to combine charts (I looked into this because we are used this inside our company)

[Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) => free (to some extent) lets you combine charts but on the same series (if I'm not missing something)

[Chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/) => free, lets you combine charts with different series, but does not seem to have a Gantt chart (again correct me if I'm wrong).

Why is this necessary?

We are developing a system where fruit growers can estimate their expected yield for a certain amount of cultivations. Each harvest period will be displayed in a Gantt chart for every cultivation. Mapping on top of that the expected and the actual yield (hence line chart).


Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we ended up going for [Plotly](https://plotly.com/). It supports graph with multi yaxis, line charts, no gantts charts specificly (at least not the JS version of plotly) but it could easily mimic one with normal line charts.